# What sort of bugs does the “Misuse of Keychain Services API” analysis find?

Tags: xcode, clang, keychain, clang-static-analyzer

Xcode 4.6 has a build setting labeled “Misuse of Keychain Services API”, a.k.a. `CLANG_ANALYZER_SECURITY_KEYCHAIN_API`. The Quick Help is unhelpful:

> Check for misuse of Keychain Services API.

So, what sort of “misuses” does the Clang Static Analyzer look for when this is on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's intended to ensure that memory allocated by functions in the Keychain Services API is deallocated in the correct manner by the caller. For instance, `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword` returns password data via an output parameter. The caller is required to deallocate this data via `SecKeychainItemFreeContent` rather than alternative APIs like `free`. Failing to use the correct API can leave sensitive data (e.g., the password) in memory.

You can see the implementation of this checker in the [LLVM SVN repository](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/MacOSKeychainAPIChecker.cpp?view=markup) if you're interested in more detail.

Comment: I am seeing this in my BuildSettings under [ Static Analyzer - Issues - Security ] but in front it there is also an option with YES and No. I am confused what it actually means.. e.g there is written 'Misuse of KeyChain Services API' and in front of it I have an option with YES and NO. Does it mean if i set it to NO it will not misuse or something. Seems absurd. Any help ?

Comment: The setting controls whether that particular analyzer check is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Comments in [the source code](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/MacOSKeychainAPIChecker.cpp?revision=175812&view=markup) explain that:

```
// This checker flags misuses of KeyChainAPI. In particular, the password data
// allocated/returned by SecKeychainItemCopyContent,
// SecKeychainFindGenericPassword, SecKeychainFindInternetPassword functions has
// to be freed using a call to SecKeychainItemFreeContent.
```

It doesn't appear to do anything more fancy than that.